# Analytic geometry reference request?

Tags: reference-request, analytic-geometry

Do you know any rigorous introduction to analytic geometry?

I'm looking for a reference which defines vectors as equivalence classes of oriented segments.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See "free vectors" in [E. Swokowski's *Calculus with analytic geometry*](https://books.google.com/books?id=gJlAOiCZRnwC&source=gbs_navlinks_s).